# Simple python code is not working

Tags: python, input, output, python-2.x

The following code is not working:

```
person = input('Enter your name: ') 
print('Hello', person)
```

Instead of printing `Hello <name>` it is giving me the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  "C:/Users/123/Desktop/123.py", line 1, in <module> 
    person = input('Enter your name: ') 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? This looks like a Python 2 error, and if it is you should use `raw_input()`

Comment: How are you running this? On the command-line, an IDE, etc? There's no d in the code, so it's odd that you're getting that answer.

Comment: you should add that you input this "d"

Comment: When getting started with Python, it is important to be clear on whether you are using Python 2.7 or Python 3.x. In 2017, 3.x is recommended for those that are not maintaining a legacy codebase. So if it doesn't matter to you which you use, you could fix the above by changing which Python you use, rather than changing the code.

Either way, be aware of this sort of issue going forward.

Answer (score 2):

To read strings you should use:

```
person = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
print('Hello', person)
```

When you use `input` it reads numbers or refers to variables instead. This happens when you are using `Python 2.7` or below. With `Python 3` and above you have only `input` function.

Your error states that you entered "d" which is a variable not declared in your code.

So if you had this code instead:

```
d = "Test"
person = input("Enter your name: ")
print('Hello', person)
```

And you type now "d" as name, you would get as output:

```
>>> 
('Hello', 'Test')
```

Answer (score 2):

## What is the error?

You used this:

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')
```

You should have used this:

```
person = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
```

## Why these are different

`input` tries to evaluate what is passed to it and returns the value, whereas `raw_input` just reads a string, meaning if you want to just read a string you need to use `raw_input`

In Python 3 `input` is gone, and `raw_input` is now called `input`, although if you **really** want the old behaviour `exec(input())` has the old behaviour.